# R - Change starting point of a line

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot a graph from a list of values stored in a vector.
I have a list of 1000 elements and another one of 900 elements.
I'd like to start to draw my second line at x=100 to make sure the last point of both lines are at x=1000.
I can't use "padding" by adding 0 to the second data vector.
I found the segment function which allow to draw from a starting to an end point but it seems that it can only draw..segments?

Do you know what option I should use to begin the drawing of a line to a given abscissa ?

Comment: Use `points()` with the argument `type = "l"`

Comment: I did, how can I specify the starting point with the points function ?

Comment: `points(x=101:1000, y=vec_of_900, type="l")`